# What does "and then some" mean and why is it used that way?

Tags: idioms, slang

It seems that a good explanation of "and then some" is:

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/and+then+some
>
> and then some
>    (Informal) With considerably more in addition: This
>   project will take all our skill and then some.

Is this a quite accurate definition? (with the stress of "considerably more").  Why is it like that, I wonder -- is it a short form of something, such as "and then some more" or "and then some considerably more amount"?  Actually, just from the word "some", it seems it is a little more or somewhat more, without the meaning of "considerably more".

Comment: Closely related: [Is “and then some” an offensive expression?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73033/10041)

Comment: @Daniel: You should really go back and update your answer on that earlier question to include a clear definition of the expression. Then we can just close this one as a dup.

Comment: @動靜能量: (I hope not too many users here adopt that kind of monicker - they'll all just merge into a single "user:squiggle" for me). I just wanted to point out that I'm not convinced *"and then some"* implies *"**considerably** more"*, so much as it implies that what came before it was considerably large already.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Done, check it out.  I can't vote to close as dupe, since I already voted for gen ref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Macmillan dictionary has this entry for *[and then some](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/some)*:

> : used for emphasizing that there is more in addition to what you have
>   mentioned
>
> *The house must have cost half a million dollars and then some.*

Macmillan also notes that *and then some* is generally a *spoken* expression.

Comment: I like this - although the implications of 'large amounts' that are being bandied about have nothing to do with this expression in my experience. My grandparents were dressmakers and I worked in a fabric store. This is a very common expression in those realms: "Do you think a yard of fabric is enough to make a collar for this suit?"  "It's enough (or, plenty) and then some."

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a quite accurate definition? (with the stress of "considerably more"). Why is it like that, I wonder -- is it a short form of something, such as "and then some more"

In a word - yes.

Answer (score 2):

"And then some" is an idiomatic expression, intentionally understated for effect.